# How to know if draged down or up while using DragGesture() in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using DragGesture() in my SwiftUI code..which working fine..but for one logic i want to know if its drag down or Up, is there any way to detect this?

```
    let drag = DragGesture()
        .onChanged { value in

            //some logic

        }
        .onEnded { value in
            // some logic 
            expand.toggle()
        }
```

Comment: Store value.location in temporary variable and compare its .y on every change, updating it again for next comparison.

Comment: Normally the value of `value.location.y` is positive when the view is dragged down and negative when the view is dragged up

Comment: @Asperi can you please explain how..if I store it in onchange, every-time i will get same value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible approach is to have additional state property to store
`value.location.y` coordinate and update dependent state comparing
previously stored and currently received in drag `value`:

Tested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

[image: demo]

Here is main part:

```
.gesture(DragGesture()
    .onChanged { value in
        let newValue = value.location.y   // fetch prev !!
        if let prev = self.current {
            self.isUp = prev > newValue   // << here !!
        }
        self.current = newValue   // store curr !!
        self.offsetY = value.translation.height
    }
```

Complete [findings and code is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/Answers/Draged_down_up_in_DragGesture.md)